# Wildfly request.getRemoteUser() returns null when accessed through nginx basic authentication

Tags: nginx, http-post, wildfly, reverse-proxy, basic-authentication

I have Wildfly 24 behind a nginx webserver, acting as a reverse proxy with Basic Authentication. When I access my services with Insomnia I can send a POST (and that works) but the problem is that `request.getRemoteUser()` returns NULL, instead of the authenticated user from Basic Authentication, and I need that value in my application.

This is my nginx configuration

```
  location / {
    auth_basic "Application auth";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://wildfly/;

    include snippets/services.conf;

    return 404;
  }
```

where `snippets/services.conf` contains just a lot of rewrites for legacy reasons.

I have experimented with adding `proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;` and `proxy_pass_header Authorization;` but that has so far not yielded any results. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a request logger to Wildfly and thus log requests with headers directly into `server.log`.

1. Create a custom filter for Undertow, using the RequestDumpingHandler
2. Add this filter to the default server

Start the CLI (`bin/jboss-cli.sh -c`) and enter the following commands

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/custom-filter=request-logger:add(module=io.undertow.core, class-name=io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=request-logger:add()
reload
```

Remove the logger with these commands:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=request-logger:remove
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/custom-filter=request-logger:remove
reload
```